# Unable to import tensorflow in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow

Edit: This seems to be a problem in some versions of Windows. I tried the same in Linux OS and it finally worked.

Inside my virtual environment, I installed tensorflow. Then tried to import it into python, but ImportError.

I've tried ALL hacks available on the internet, but none of them seem to work for me. Please help.

- Tried downloading necessary DLLs (in system32 folder)
- Tried changing environment path variable
- Tried uninstalling and reinstalling Python and tensorflow in various ways
- Tried upgrading setup tools

**Basic import command**

```
E:\tensor1>myenv\Scripts\activate.bat

(myenv) E:\tensor1>python

>>> import tensorflow
```

Whatever I try, this error is relentlessly showing up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\tensor1\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.p
y", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "E:\tensor1\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_i
nternal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "E:\tensor1\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_i
nternal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\samiam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line
 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\samiam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line
 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\tensor1\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 28, in
<module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "E:\tensor1\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line
49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "E:\tensor1\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.p
y", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\tensor1\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.p
y", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "E:\tensor1\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_i
nternal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "E:\tensor1\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_i
nternal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\samiam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line
 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\samiam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line
 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

Comment: How exactly did you set up this environment? You mention having tried several things, but it will be hard for somebody to reproduce without at least one specific example. Also, what are the details of your OS? I assume this is some sort of Windows?

Comment: Are you using `tensorflow-gpu`?

Comment: Please edit the question reflect how you set up the environment! In addition make sure you installed the correct tensorflow whether its gpu or not

Comment: Yes @Nathan it is on windows.

Comment: I'm not sure about the gpu, as on tensorflow.org it said the command i used to install should work just fine on all cpu.

Comment: Try system-wide install and avoid installing in virtual env.